# How do I pass function arguments in an "unordered" manner (in relation to the function declaration)?

Tags: c++, function, variables, arguments, unordered

I don't really know how to word or explain this very well, I think that this is a simple question but I just can't find an answer online.

I want to kind of "jump" some arguments in my (C++) function. Example below:

```
void func(int a=1, int b=2, int c=3, int d=5) {
    // Do stuff
}

int main(void)
{
    func();
}
```

How do I pass, for example, something that would set d to 4 using the other variables default arguments (only passing an argument for d)?
Something like:

```
void func(int a=1, int b=2, int c=3, int d=5) {
    // Do stuff
}

int main(void)
{
    func(d=4);
}
```

I tried the code above, and it does not work as intended, but I think you get the point, how do I set a variable to something without going trough all the other ones?

An example of what I **don't** want:

```
void func(int a=1, int b=2, int c=3, int d=5) {
    // Do stuff
}

int main(void)
{
    func(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Any suggestions/answers? I remember that I used to do something like this in Python, but I can't figure out how to do it in C++.

Comment: You cannot do that in C++. Sorry. If you need Python it's still there.

Comment: What you are looking for is ["named arguments"](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/14/named-arguments-cpp/), ie `func(d=4);` or `func(d: 4);` Unfortunately, this feature is not part of the C++ standard (it was [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4172.htm) several years ago but was not adopted). So, when passing an argument value explicitly, all arguments to the left MUST also be passed explicitly and in the declared order, only arguments to the right can remain defaulted.